# SQL Percentage of an item to total for all

Tags: sql, percentage

I have three heads

```
Scheme| Account| Nav_date| Amount
DYFF  |INVEQU  | 25/01/2013|  100
DYFF  |INVCOD  | 25/01/2013|  100
GBGF  |INVEQU  | 25/01/2013|  200
GBGF  |INVCOD  | 25/01/2013|  100
DYFF  |INVEQU  | 26/01/2013|  150
DYFF  |INVCOD  | 26/01/2013|  150
```

I want an SQL query to Get % of INVEQU to Total Amount for that Date for that Scheme for each Date for Scheme ="DYFF"

So Answer would be like

```
Scheme| Account| nav_date| Percentage
DYFF  |INVEQU  |25/01/2013 | 50%
DYFF  |INVEQU  |26/01/2013 | 50%
```

I am using Oracle Database

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Schemes AS
(
    SELECT
     *
    ,ROUND(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL(18, 2))/SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY Scheme, Value_Date)*100, 2) AS Percentage
    FROM (VALUES
     ('DYFF'  ,'INVEQU'  , '25/01/2013',  100)
    ,('DYFF'  ,'INVCOD'  , '25/01/2013',  100)
    ,('GBGF'  ,'INVEQU'  , '25/01/2013',  200)
    ,('GBGF'  ,'INVCOD'  , '25/01/2013',  100)
    ,('DYFF'  ,'INVEQU'  , '26/01/2013',  150)
    ,('DYFF'  ,'INVCOD'  , '26/01/2013',  150)) v(Scheme, Account, Value_Date, Amount)
)
SELECT
 *
FROM Schemes
WHERE Scheme='DYFF'
AND Account='INVEQU';
```

or in your case

```
WITH Schemes AS
(
    SELECT
     *
    ,ROUND(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL(18, 2))/SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY Scheme, Value_Date)*100, 2) AS Percentage
    FROM YOUR_TABLE
)
SELECT
 *
FROM Schemes
WHERE Scheme='DYFF'
AND Account='INVEQU';
```

Comment: Hi the dates are not limited to two dates but can run into years

Comment: That's ok - the query will still work as the SUM is partitioned by date

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
  select scheme
       , 'INVEQU'    account
       , value_date
       , case tl
            when 0 then 0
            else        100*COALESCE(tl_i,0)/tl
         end         percentage
    from (
                select agg_i.tl             tl_i
                     , agg_tl.tl            tl
                     , agg_tl.scheme
                     , agg_tl.value_date
                  from (
                            select scheme
                                 , value_date
                                 , sum(amount)  tl
                              from table t_tl
                          group by scheme,
                                 , value_date
                        ) agg_tl 
              LEFT JOIN
                        (         
                            select scheme
                                 , value_date
                                 , sum(amount)  tl
                              from table t_i
                             where account = 'INVEQU'
                          group by scheme,
                                 , value_date
                        ) agg_i
                     ON (     agg_i.scheme       = agg_tl.scheme  
                          AND agg_i.value_date   = agg_tl.value_date  )        
          ) pct
          ;
```

Comment: Hi,Is there a way to do this using partition. I know it should matter. but I am not able to understand above query. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: the innermost subqueries both sum over the base table grouped by the combination of scheme and value_date. while the first one (`agg_tl`) acts on all base table records, the second one (`agg_i`) limits itself to records with the account `INVEQU`. this information is joined over scheme, value_date to provide the pair of frequencies needed to compute the percentage. the other parts serve to catch corner cases. in particular the left join caters for scheme/value_date combinations without `INVEQU` account records (**this was not part of the original solution**).

Answer (score 0):

I would use this simple approach. Force a CrossJoin with a 1 result only SUM Table and apply it to each of the rows.

```
SELECT 
     T.Scheme, T.Account, T.Nav_Date, SUM(T.Amount), SUM(T.Amount)/T2.Total
FROM 
    Table1 T,
    (SELECT SUM(Amount) as Total FROM Table1) T2
WHERE
    T.Scheme = 'DYFF'
GROUP BY
    T.Scheme, T.Account. T.Nav_Date
```